# Indenting a nested form in an HTML template

Tags: html, django

This may be more of a HTML question but there is DJANGO code in my HTML template. I have a list of teachers and a nested form that contain students associated with each teacher. Is there a way to indent the student list when it's being rendered underneath a teacher? I don't know what where to put the HTML code. I've tried a few things in various places but nothing indents.

```
<div class="form-block">
     {{ teachers.management_form }}
     {% for teacher in teachers.forms %}
        {{ teacher }}

        {% if teacher.nested %}
           {% for studentformset in teacher.nested %}
              {{ studentformset.as_table }}
           {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}

     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Browser Source snippet

```
 <option value="50">dd</option>
 </select></td></tr>
 <tr><th><label for="id_value_35-0-student">Student Names:</label></th><td>      <input id="id_value_35-0-student" type="text" name="value_35-0-student"    value="2" maxlength="50" /><input type="hidden" name="value_35-0-id" value="14"    id="id_value_35-0-id" /></td></tr> <tr><th><label for="id_value_35-1-   student">Teacher:</label></th><td><select name="value_35-1-student"    id="id_value_35-1-student">
 <option value="">---------</option>
 <option value="1">df</option>
<option value="2">df</option>
```

Comment: When you say indent, do you mean visually in the browser? If so, click view-source on your page, and paste the html into your question please..

Comment: yea i mean visually in the browser. I updated and added a snippet.

Comment: What for then? When you are using Firebug or Chrome dev tools. The HTML is ***always** indented.

Comment: I'd like to the render the student names indented. But it's not showing up as indented even when I add nbsp; to the 2nd for loop.